# Highcharts line chart tooltips not showing correctly?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a simple line chart, but something strange is happening with the tooltips. It seems that only the first and last point shows tooltip data, for some reason it can't seem to pick anything in between. The chart is fairly simply so I'm not sure what it could be, unless it has something to do with the datetime axis?

I'd appreciate any ideas.

http://jsfiddle.net/kJ47n/

edit: Here is an even simpler version
http://jsfiddle.net/kJ47n/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the problem is your X values is unsorted, I sorted the array by the X value and is working fine, look:

http://jsfiddle.net/9H6h2/

Or your data array is wrong, something like this make more sense to me:

```
var ldlData = [[100,1336535631000], [110, 1304913231000], [120, 1273377231000], [130, 1241841231000], [140, 1210305231000], [150, 1178682831000]];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you sir, I had the data sorted by most recent and reversing that fixed it right up. Appreciate it.